# A simple math program in c is giving the wrong answer. Where is the error?

Tags: c, math, operators, arithmetic-expressions

The following code should output: 2.000000, but it gives -0.000000.
Where exactly I am getting things wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  // number of iterations = k.
  int k = 100;
  long double sum = 0;
  for (int n = 0; n < k; n++)
    sum += 1 / pow(2, n);
  printf("series sum = %lf", sum);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("series sum = %lf", sum);` -> `printf("series sum = %Lf", sum);`

Comment: @DavidRanieri that doesn't change anything. still getting -0.000000.

Comment: Should work: https://ideone.com/gbe4Xm

Comment: thanks @DavidRanieri it worked. i am using gcc compiler and for some reason it doesn't work there. thanks.

Comment: You are welcome, I'm also compiling with gcc and it works for me, try `gcc -std=c99 demo.c -o demo -lm`

Comment: What is your environment? Is it MinGW under Windows as addressed in the duplicate? Something else?

Comment: @Gerhardh it's mingw.